# mongosh/mongo shell installation issues: "command not found"

Tags: mongodb, windows, installation, mongo-shell

I am following the Udemy Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp for using and working with MongoDB. I tried using mongod and mongo commands as Angela does in her tutorial but of course it is outdated and they don't work.

After doing some research I was directed to the MongoDB website and found the the newer versions require you to have the mongosh shell downloaded with the correct file path added to the environment variables in the control panel for windows. I've completed all necessary steps per the documentation on the MongoDB website, however when I get to the very last step and open up a new terminal to type in "mongosh --help" as it indicates, I receive "bash: C:Program: command not found".

I even went back into the .bash_profile and tried changing the alias (like in Angela's course) to "mongosh" with the updated file path pointing to the mongosh.exe binary, and still command not found.

Comment: as long as mongosh path in the PATH env variable, you only need to restart your terminal to make this change visible

Answer (score 0):

I just answered my own question: when adding the mongosh alias in the vim .bash_profile, the slashes need to be oriented as "/" between each file folder in the path, whereas when the file path is copied and pasted, windows automatically uses backwards "" slashes and therefore the file could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error because I forgot where my mongosh path is. So I had to uninstall and reinstall mongoDB shell as it would show me the path. So just make sure to have these 2 in the PATH variable in User variables. My second path is: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh because mongosh is the folder that stores *mongosh.exe* so you should be able to run mongosh in command line now after this.

[image]